# from utils import Config--ImportError: cannot import name 'Config'

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python 3.5, I get the following import error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Config'
```

when I try

```
from utils import Config
```

I have checked that the package utils was "piped". It is curious to me because it was ok when I tried to import Config from utils a few months ago.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the `Config` module is not available in the `utils` package.

If you try a `help("utils")` in python shell after `import utils`, you will notice that utils has these modules -

bools, dates, dicts, enum, lists, math and objects but not `Config`.

According to [this](https://www.red-dove.com/config-doc/) doc (it's outdated though), `Config` is used by `from config import Config`. You might want to try `pip install config` and see if it works for your python version.

If it isn't working, you can always use `configparser`.